# Hive select only first two decimal places

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Hive select only first two decimal places.

```
Input: columnA decimal datatype value is 57.698700000
Expected output should be 57.69
```

Note:output should not be rounded to next highest or lowest value

Currently I’m using trunc(colA,2) which is giving me the output as 57.690000000000
But my expected output should be 57.69
Please help me on this
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROUND` function in Hive.

As the Hive documentation say:

```
round(DOUBLE a, INT d)

Returns a rounded to d decimal places.
```

As an example:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(58.3265487, 2) AS num_round;

+------------+--+
| num_round  |
+------------+--+
| 58.33      |
+------------+--+

SELECT ROUND(58.3265487, 3) AS num_round;

+------------+--+
| num_round  |
+------------+--+
| 58.327     |
+------------+--+
```

or if you want to round to the exact decimal, you could try as follow:

```sql
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(SPLIT(71.42857142857143, '\\.')[0],'.', SUBSTRING(SPLIT(71.42857142857143, '\\.')[1], 1, 2)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS number_rounded;

+-----------------+--+
| number_rounded  |
+-----------------+--+
| 71.42           |
+-----------------+--+
```

Comment: My output should be 58.32 as per your example  but not 58.33

Comment: I was making up another example.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default feature of Hive since 0.14 version. Based on the scale it will consider the digits after period.  If you are ok to have scale as 2 then your problem will be resolved.

For more details check this hive enhancement.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7373

0 in decimal(5,4) would be 0
0.0 in decimal(5,4) would be 0.0
0.00 in decimal(5,4) would be 0.00
0.00000000 in decimal(5,4) would be 0.0000

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods:

```
 round(col - 0.005, 2)
 floor(col * 100) / 100.0
```